# How can I save and restore the state of a Delphi component properly?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to save the state of a component and later restore it.  I have made a little class helper to do so but the order of the way Delphi restores the class is causing a problem. It restores the Delimiter correctly but then sets RecordFormat which in turn over writes the Delimiter to be a semi colon.  So I end up with the wrong value. Do you have any suggestions how I could get round this?  I liked the simplicity of using a class helper but it will get convoluted if I have to handle it afterwards.

```
interface

type
  TFDBatchMoveTextReaderHelper = class helper for TFDBatchMoveTextReader
  private
    function GetState: String;
    procedure SetState( const Value: String );
  published
    property State: String read GetState write SetState;
  end;


implementation

function ComponentToStringProc( Component: TComponent ): string;
var
  BinStream: TMemoryStream;
  StrStream: TStringStream;
  s        : string;
begin
  BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    StrStream := TStringStream.Create( s );
    try
      BinStream.WriteComponent( Component );
      BinStream.Seek( 0, soFromBeginning );
      ObjectBinaryToText( BinStream, StrStream );
      StrStream.Seek( 0, soFromBeginning );
      Result := StrStream.DataString;
    finally
      StrStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    BinStream.Free
  end;
end;

procedure StrtoComp( Value: string; AComponent: TComponent );
var
  StrStream: TStringStream;
  BinStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  StrStream := TStringStream.Create( Value );
  try
    BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      ObjectTextToBinary( StrStream, BinStream );
      BinStream.Seek( 0, soFromBeginning );
      BinStream.ReadComponent( AComponent );
    finally
      BinStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    StrStream.Free;
  end;
end;


{ TFDBatchMoveTextReaderHelper }

function TFDBatchMoveTextReaderHelper.GetState: String;
begin
  Result := ComponentToStringProc( Self );
end;

procedure TFDBatchMoveTextReaderHelper.SetState( const Value: String );
begin
  StrtoComp( Value, Self );
end;

initialization

RegisterClass( TFDBatchMoveTextReader );

end.
```

And here are my results (ignore the difference in the filename, I changed that before logging the state again.  It's the DataDef values I am having problems with)

```
Text Compare
Produced: 27/03/2020 07:56:58

Mode:  All
Left file: Clipboard at 27/03/2020 07:54:09     Right file: Clipboard at 27/03/2020 07:54:18
AReaderState from the database = object TextReader: TFDBatchMoveTextReader <> lReader.State after applied to the object = object TextReader: TFDBatchMoveTextReader
  FileName = 'c:\molen\impexp\import\adm_loads_foynes.csv'                      FileName =
                                                                                  'C:\Users\stevesinclair\AppData\Local\Temp\96FFA4BD1C064E77972398' +
                                                                                  '7AD6E15495\adm_loads_foynes.csv'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  DataDef.Fields = <                                                       =    DataDef.Fields = <
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'LOAD_ID'                                                         FieldName = 'LOAD_ID'
      DataType = atLongInt                                                          DataType = atLongInt
      FieldSize = 9                                                                 FieldSize = 9
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'SITE_ID'                                                         FieldName = 'SITE_ID'
      DataType = atLongInt                                                          DataType = atLongInt
      FieldSize = 5                                                                 FieldSize = 5
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'VEHICLE_REG'                                                     FieldName = 'VEHICLE_REG'
      DataType = atString                                                           DataType = atString
      FieldSize = 32                                                                FieldSize = 32
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'CREATED_BY'                                                      FieldName = 'CREATED_BY'
      DataType = atString                                                           DataType = atString
      FieldSize = 32                                                                FieldSize = 32
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'UPDATED_BY'                                                      FieldName = 'UPDATED_BY'
      DataType = atString                                                           DataType = atString
      FieldSize = 32                                                                FieldSize = 32
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'LDD_ID'                                                          FieldName = 'LDD_ID'
      DataType = atLongInt                                                          DataType = atLongInt
      FieldSize = 9                                                                 FieldSize = 9
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'TRANS_TYPE_ID'                                                   FieldName = 'TRANS_TYPE_ID'
      DataType = atLongInt                                                          DataType = atLongInt
      FieldSize = 3                                                                 FieldSize = 3
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'STAGE_ID'                                                        FieldName = 'STAGE_ID'
      DataType = atLongInt                                                          DataType = atLongInt
      FieldSize = 1                                                                 FieldSize = 1
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'ACCOUNT_ID'                                                      FieldName = 'ACCOUNT_ID'
      DataType = atLongInt                                                          DataType = atLongInt
      FieldSize = 9                                                                 FieldSize = 9
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'COMMODITY_ID'                                                    FieldName = 'COMMODITY_ID'
      DataType = atLongInt                                                          DataType = atLongInt
      FieldSize = 9                                                                 FieldSize = 9
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'FLN_ID'                                                          FieldName = 'FLN_ID'
      DataType = atLongInt                                                          DataType = atLongInt
      FieldSize = 9                                                                 FieldSize = 9
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'TLN_ID'                                                          FieldName = 'TLN_ID'
      DataType = atLongInt                                                          DataType = atLongInt
      FieldSize = 9                                                                 FieldSize = 9
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'NET_WEIGHT'                                                      FieldName = 'NET_WEIGHT'
      DataType = atLongInt                                                          DataType = atLongInt
      FieldSize = 5                                                                 FieldSize = 5
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'CREATED_DATE'                                                    FieldName = 'CREATED_DATE'
      DataType = atDateTime                                                         DataType = atDateTime
      FieldSize = 19                                                                FieldSize = 19
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'UPDATED_DATE'                                                    FieldName = 'UPDATED_DATE'
      DataType = atDate                                                             DataType = atDate
      FieldSize = 10                                                                FieldSize = 10
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'UPDATED_TIME'                                                    FieldName = 'UPDATED_TIME'
      DataType = atTime                                                             DataType = atTime
      FieldSize = 8                                                                 FieldSize = 8
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'TRAILER_REG'                                                     FieldName = 'TRAILER_REG'
      DataType = atString                                                           DataType = atString
      FieldSize = 6                                                                 FieldSize = 6
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'TRANSACTION_DATE'                                                FieldName = 'TRANSACTION_DATE'
      DataType = atDateTime                                                         DataType = atDateTime
      FieldSize = 19                                                                FieldSize = 19
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'IOX'                                                             FieldName = 'IOX'
      DataType = atString                                                           DataType = atString
      FieldSize = 1                                                                 FieldSize = 1
    end                                                                           end
    item                                                                          item
      FieldName = 'SHIP_ID'                                                         FieldName = 'SHIP_ID'
      DataType = atLongInt                                                          DataType = atLongInt
      FieldSize = 9                                                                 FieldSize = 9
    end>                                                                          end>
  DataDef.Delimiter = '"'                                                       DataDef.Delimiter = '"'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  DataDef.Separator = ','                                                  <>   DataDef.Separator = ';'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  DataDef.RecordFormat = rfCustom                                          =    DataDef.RecordFormat = rfCustom
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  DataDef.FormatSettings.DateSeparator = '/'                               +-
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  DataDef.FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY'                    =    DataDef.FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  DataDef.FormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat = 'HH:mm:ss'                           DataDef.FormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat = 'HH:mm:ss'
  Left = 430                                                                    Left = 430
  Top = 20                                                                      Top = 20
end                                                                           end
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is a test that I wrote for this which passes.

```
procedure TMyTestObject.TestReaderStaterfCustom;
var
  LOriginalReader: TFDBatchMoveTextReader;
  LRestoredReader: TFDBatchMoveTextReader;
const
  LDelimiter    = '|';
  LSeparator   = ',';
begin
  LOriginalReader := TFDBatchMoveTextReader.Create( nil );
  LRestoredReader := TFDBatchMoveTextReader.Create( nil );
  try
    LOriginalReader.DataDef.RecordFormat := rfCustom;
    LOriginalReader.DataDef.Delimiter    := LDelimiter;
    LOriginalReader.DataDef.Separator    := LSeparator;

    LRestoredReader.State := LOriginalReader.State;

    Assert.AreEqual( LOriginalReader.State, LRestoredReader.State, 'LOriginalReader.State, LRestoredReader.State (after setting)' );
    Assert.AreEqual( LOriginalReader.DataDef.Delimiter, LRestoredReader.DataDef.Delimiter );
    Assert.AreEqual( LOriginalReader.DataDef.Separator, LRestoredReader.DataDef.Separator );
    Assert.AreEqual( LDelimiter, LRestoredReader.DataDef.Delimiter );
    Assert.AreEqual( LSeparator, LRestoredReader.DataDef.Separator );

  finally
    LOriginalReader.Free;
    LRestoredReader.Free;
  end;

end;
```

But when I try to use it in my application it fails.  I've put some logging round the setter as follows:

```
procedure TFDBatchMoveTextReaderHelper.SetState( const Value: String );
begin
  CodeSite.Send( 'TFDBatchMoveTextReaderHelper.SetState', Value );
  StrtoComp( Value, Self );
  CodeSite.Send( 'self.DataDef.Separator', self.DataDef.Separator );
end;
```

Which logs the separator as self.DataDef.Separator = ; which makes no sense as the value in the state string string is:

```
DataDef.Delimiter = '"'
DataDef.Separator = ','
DataDef.RecordFormat = rfCustom
DataDef.FormatSettings.DateSeparator = '/'
DataDef.FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY'
DataDef.FormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat = 'HH:mm:ss'
```

And this is how I am actually using it in the application:

```
      lConn := TFDConnection.Create( nil );
  try
    lConn.ConnectionDefName := AConnectionDefName;
    lMover                  := TFDBatchMove.Create( lConn );
    lMemTable               := TFDMemTable.Create( lConn );
    lReader                 := TFDBatchMoveTextReader.Create( lConn );
    lReader.State           := AReaderState;
    lReader.FileName        := lTempFileName;
    lWriter                 := TFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter.Create( lConn );
    lWriter.Dataset         := lMemTable;
    lQuery                  := TFDQuery.Create( lConn );
    lQuery.Connection       := lConn;
    lQuery.SQL.Text         := ATargetSQL;
    try
      lQuery.Prepare;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        CodeSite.SendException( Format( 'Error perparing query: %s', [ ATargetSQL ] ), E );
        raise;
      end
    end;
    lMover.Reader := lReader;
    lMover.Writer := lWriter;
```

Comment: This code is using a DFM stream to save the component. A DFM stores only non-default property values. So when reading a DFM, you have to first make sure the target component instance is already in its default state before you then read the DFM stream into it. Are you doing that? This is typically handled automatically by loading a DFM only into a newly constructed instance, not into an existing instance.  If you reuse an existing instance, you have to reset it manually first.

Comment: Thanks Remy but it is a new instance that I am using it for.  I've edited my question to try and explain the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked round this setting the separator and delimiter after applying the state string.  In my rests I found that the order of how the state is saved was causing the problem. If DataDef.RecordFormat is before DataDef.Delimiter and DataDef.Separator it worked.  However I have no control of how that is saved so I have hacked it when reading it back.

```
procedure TFDBatchMoveTextReaderHelper.SetState( const Value: String );
var
  RegEx: TRegEx;
  Match: TMatch;
const
  PatternRecordFormat = 'DataDef\.RecordFormat *= *(rfCustom)';
  PatternSeparator    = 'DataDef\.Separator *= *''(.)''';
  PatternDelimiter    = 'DataDef\.Delimiter *= *''(.)''';
begin
  StrtoComp( Value, Self );

  RegEx := TRegEx.Create( PatternRecordFormat, [ roIgnoreCase, roMultiLine ] );
  Match := RegEx.Match( Value );
  if Match.Success and ( Match.Groups.Count > 1 ) then
  begin
    RegEx := TRegEx.Create( PatternSeparator, [ roIgnoreCase, roMultiLine ] );
    Match := RegEx.Match( Value );
    if Match.Success and ( Match.Groups.Count > 1 ) then
      Self.DataDef.Separator := ( Match.Groups[ 1 ].Value + ',' )[ 1 ];

    RegEx := TRegEx.Create( PatternDelimiter, [ roIgnoreCase, roMultiLine ] );
    Match := RegEx.Match( Value );
    if Match.Success and ( Match.Groups.Count > 1 ) then
      Self.DataDef.Delimiter := ( Match.Groups[ 1 ].Value + '"' )[ 1 ];
  end;

end;
```

Not the best answer I know but it's all I could come up with.  Here's my test to confirm it worked.

```
[ Test ]
[ TestCase( 'Comma Double Quote', 'rfCommaDoubleQuote' ) ]
[ TestCase( 'Semicolon Double Quote', 'rfSemicolonDoubleQuote' ) ]
[ TestCase( 'Tab Double Quote', 'rfTabDoubleQuote' ) ]
[ TestCase( 'Fixed Length', 'rfFixedLength' ) ]
[ TestCase( 'Field Per Line', 'rfFieldPerLine' ) ]
[ TestCase( 'Bar Double Quote', 'rfCustom' ) ]
procedure TestReaderState( const ARecordFormat: TFDTextRecordFormat );


procedure TMyTestObject.TestReaderState( const ARecordFormat: TFDTextRecordFormat );
var
  LOriginalReader: TFDBatchMoveTextReader;
  LRestoredReader: TFDBatchMoveTextReader;
  LDelimiter     : Char;
  LSeparator     : Char;
  LWithFieldNames: Boolean;
begin
  LOriginalReader := TFDBatchMoveTextReader.Create( nil );
  LRestoredReader := TFDBatchMoveTextReader.Create( nil );
  try
    case ARecordFormat of
      rfCommaDoubleQuote:
        begin
          LDelimiter := #34;
          LSeparator := #44;
        end;
      rfSemicolonDoubleQuote:
        begin
          LDelimiter := #34;
          LSeparator := #59;
        end;
      rfTabDoubleQuote:
        begin
          LDelimiter := #34;
          LSeparator := #9;
        end;
      rfFixedLength:
        begin
          LDelimiter      := #0;
          LSeparator      := #0;
          LWithFieldNames := False;
        end;
      rfFieldPerLine:
        begin
          LDelimiter      := #0;
          LSeparator      := #0;
          LWithFieldNames := False;
        end;
      rfCustom:
        begin
          LDelimiter := #124;
          LSeparator := #44;
        end;
    else
      begin
        LDelimiter := #34;
        LSeparator := #59;
      end;
    end;
    LOriginalReader.DataDef.RecordFormat := ARecordFormat;
    if LOriginalReader.DataDef.RecordFormat = ARecordFormat then
    begin
      LOriginalReader.DataDef.Delimiter := LDelimiter;
      LOriginalReader.DataDef.Separator := LSeparator;
    end;

    LRestoredReader.State := LOriginalReader.State;

    Assert.AreEqual( LOriginalReader.State, LRestoredReader.State, 'LOriginalReader.State, LRestoredReader.State (after setting)' );
    Assert.AreEqual( LOriginalReader.DataDef.Delimiter, LRestoredReader.DataDef.Delimiter );
    Assert.AreEqual( LOriginalReader.DataDef.Separator, LRestoredReader.DataDef.Separator );
    Assert.AreEqual( LDelimiter, LRestoredReader.DataDef.Delimiter );
    Assert.AreEqual( LSeparator, LRestoredReader.DataDef.Separator );
    Assert.AreEqual( LOriginalReader.DataDef.WithFieldNames, LRestoredReader.DataDef.WithFieldNames )

  finally
    LOriginalReader.Free;
    LRestoredReader.Free;
  end;

end;
```